# BeautifulSoup assign multiple tag .text to variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have a HTML website with the following code:

```
<div class="random-texts">
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>def</p>
    <p>ghi</p>
</div>
```

I have tried to use tags = soup.select('div[class="random-texts" > p'), and doing so returns a list:

```
[<p>abc</p>, <p>def</p>, <p>ghi</p>]
```

To extract the texts, I use a for loop to iterate over the elements:

```
for tag in tags:
    tag.text

abc
def
ghi
```

So my question is, how do I store all of the texts from the paragraphs into a variable (e.g. paragraphs_texts)

```
print(paragraph_texts)
abc def ghi
```

Apologies if this sounds like a stupidly obvious question.

I'm not very skilled in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "put all of the texts from the paragraphs into a variable"? include your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="random-texts">
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>def</p>
    <p>ghi</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

val = list(soup.select_one("div.random-texts").stripped_strings)

print(val)

# or unpacking

print(*val)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

And

```
abc def ghi
```

Comment: Thank you! I just want to clarify something though. Is it not possible to get the texts if using soup.select instead of soup.select_one?

Comment: @ShawnTheMaroon47 `val = [list(item.stripped_strings) for item in soup.select("div.random-texts")]`